# How to upgrade python version in Databricks

Tags: python, python-3.x, databricks, azure-databricks

We upgraded `Databricks` from `10.3` to `10.4 LTS`. But the `python` version did not change from `python 3.8.10`.

**Question**: In `Databricks - version 10.4`, how can we upgrade the python version from `python 3.8.10` to `python 3.10`?

**UPDATE**: I would like to use some new functionalities offered in python 3.10 such as [match case Statement](https://learnpython.com/blog/python-match-case-statement/).

Comment: what is the reason for upgrade? What functionality do you want to add with it?

Comment: @AlexOtt Good question (that made me add an **UPDATE** section to my post above).

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to install python 3.10.5 on a Docker image that a cluster can utilise instead of the standard runtime.

https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/custom-containers.html

You can build upon the minimal configuration. I have made a minimal example

```
FROM databricksruntime/minimal:experimental

# Installs python 3.10 and virtualenv for Spark and Notebooks
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y \
    python3.10 \
    virtualenv \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Initialize the default environment that Spark and notebooks will use
RUN virtualenv -p python3.10 --system-site-packages /databricks/python3

# Specifies where Spark will look for the python process
ENV PYSPARK_PYTHON=/databricks/python3/bin/python3
```

You will need to install all other python libraries, so the process is a bit more tedious.

Answer (score 1):

It *might not be possible to upgrade the version of python **inside a Databricks cluster***. Each cluster have a pre-defined configuration which consist of specific versions of `Spark, Scala and Python`.

> We upgraded Databricks from 10.3 to 10.4 LTS. But the python version did not change from python 3.8.10

- This is because both Databricks 10.3 and 10.4 LTS have python version as `3.8.10`.

One solution would have been to `Edit the cluster` to change to Databricks runtime which supports required configuration. To do this Navigate to `compute -> click on your cluster -> edit` and choose required databricks runtime.

But currently, the highest python version supported in Azure databricks is `Python 3.9.5` by `Databricks runtime 11.1`. Refer to [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/releases) to understand more about features and configurations of Databricks runtimes